# Celery and Django simple example

Tags: python, django, celery, scalability

Let's take a simple Django example.

app/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    token = models.CharField(max_length=32)
```

app/views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from forms import RegisterForm
from utils.utilities import create_user

@csrf_exempt
def register_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            create_user(form.cleaned_data)
            return HttpResponse('success')
```

utils/utilities.py

```
def create_user(data):
    user = User.objects.create_user(username=data['username'], email=None, password=data['password'])
    user.save()
    profile = UserProfile()
    profile.user = user
    profile.token = generate_token()
    profile.save()
```

Can somebody provide an implementation of Celery in this example? Imagine this is a large project with hundreds of requests per sec.

Comment: Just so you know, direct requests for examples tend to be regarded as off-topic, as they are frequently come from people who've not done any prior research. That clearly doesn't apply to you, but it's worth being aware of that general guideline - see the [Help](http://stackoverflow.com/help) section when you get a mo.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Assuming you have both Python's [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) and [django-celery](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-celery)  installed, create the following `tasks.py` file under your app:

**utils/tasks.py**

```
from celery import task
# other imports

@task()
def create_user(data):
    user = User.objects.create_user(
        username=data['username'], email=None, password=data['password']
    )
    user.save()
    profile = UserProfile()
    profile.user = user
    profile.token = generate_token()
    profile.save()

    return None
```

Delete your `utils/utilities.py` file in your example above.

In your code in `views.py` change the `create_user` call from:

```
create_user(form.cleaned_data)
```

to:

```
create_user.delay(form.cleaned_data)
```

Basically `create_user` is now a celery task; if you have the right Python packages installed (as mentioned above), code-wise (the implementation you ask for) that's it. `delay` executes your function asynchronously - i.e. the HTTP response is returned without waiting for the asynchronous task to complete.

Locally you can run a celery daemon process using `python manage.py celeryd`.

In production you have to set up the celery process itself using for instance `upstart`, `supervisor` or any other tool to control the lifecycle of such process.

Further details documented [here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html).

Comment: I would give you golden badges for this! Thanks so much!

Comment: I did this django-celery template project after spending some time on trying to get tasks showing up in django admin: https://github.com/mikeumus/django-celery-example 
Hope it helps someone! :)

Comment: This is useful solution. Thanks