# Multi-threading a process within a view function

Tags: django, multithreading

In `views`, I have a process that takes a few seconds to compute. As it stands, this process comes before my view function returns a next webpage. However, it is not crucial that this process runs before, and in fact it can run anytime. Therefore, I am wondering if it is possible to run this process, and then return the next webpage before the process has finished. I suppose this would be considered multi-threading.

For example:

```
def myViewFunction(request):
    myProcess() # This takes a while to finish
    return render(request, 'myapp/mywebpage.html')
```

Can I run `myProcess()` in the background, and return `render()` as soon as `myProcess()` has been called, rather than wait until it has returned?

Comment: yea just use a normal thread..

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20164820/356729) for an example of using Celery inside Django.